# Set Photo For Domain Users

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

One of the more interesting features of Windows Vista/7 is being able to set a photo to represent your user.  This is nice on a standalone installation, but is there a way to set the photo in Active Directory so that the photo is consistent no matter where the user logs in across the domain?

Comment: Why? I'm sure the use knows what he or she looks like. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it does not look like there is a built-in way for Windows Vista/7 clients to utilize the **jpegPhoto** or **thumbnailPhoto** attributes in Active Directory.

However, another option may be to write a logon script that extracts the binary data from AD and store it in **%programdata%\Microsoft\User Account Picutres\user.bmp**.  Then turn on the Group Policy setting **Apply the default user logon picture to all users** which is under Control Panel\User Accounts.

For the logon script, search for those two attribute names and you will see some sample programs for uploading/downloading the images.

Answer (score 0):

In a large organization, this would be a great way to cut down on Social Engineering attempts - particularly if you could verify someones picture via the GAL.